# Qt: How to turn off resource compression in pro-file?

Tags: qt, resources, rcc

I have read "[The Qt Resource System](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/resources.html)" article. In paragraph "Compression" there is information on how to turn off compression by parameters in rcc command line.
But rcc command line is auto-generated by qmake from pro file. If I change rcc command line directly it will be restored to original state during next qmake run.

Is it possible to turn off compression in pro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The QMake variable [QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qmake-resource-flags) allows you to pass custom flags to RCC.
To disable compression, try:

```
QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -compress 0
```

Answer (score 6):

As per the latest documentation of [Resource Compiler rcc](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/rcc.html):

```
QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -no-compress
```