# File IO using QTCreator IDE on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, io

I just started using QTCreator IDE on Linux, and I love everything about it except I ran into an issue with file IO. This doesn't concern the QT library, just the IDE and C++. The issue is that I have to specify the full path name for a file - like so:

`Shader shader ("/home/user/Documents/OpenGL/SandboxProject/vertexShader.glsl")`

In contrast, on CodeBlocks I can just do the current directory:

`Shader shader ("./vertexShader.glsl")`

Do I need to configure something in the IDE? I noticed that when I type in the terminal `which qtcreator` it is in `/usr/bin/` whereas my CodeBlocks binary is in `/usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Generally speaking, it's *wrong* to depend on the current working directory of your process. When your user will start your application, the working directory can be *anything*, unless it's a console application. You need to reference the file in the application directory, and you need to deploy it along with the executable from your project file. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26490841/1329652) details it for OS X, you'd do it similarly for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Projects` -> Select your project tab -> Select the `Run` tab -> Check the `Run` section and set the `Working directory` as you need it.

If you are developing a cross-platform Qt app, I'd recommend to use the [Qt Resource System](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/resources.html), which compiles resource files into your binary.

Comment: Oh, that was a lot easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!